# Does open components coincide with quasicomponents?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

It is known that in cases of locally connected topological spaces or compact Hausdorff spaces the components and quasicomponents coincide. Both claims can be proved using the fact that if a quasicomponent is open, then it is connected.

Does the opposite of the last claim hold too, i.e., if the component is open, does it imply that it must coincide with a quasicomponent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If a component $C$ is open, then it is clopen. It cannot contain a non-empty strictly smaller clopen subset, thus it is the intersection of all clopen subsets containing a fixed point $x \in C$.

Comment: I see. Thank you! Just for clarification, may I add that since $C$ is a clopen component, if $C$ contained a clopen nontrivial subset, then $C$ would contain a quasicomponent which is not equal to $C$ which is a contradiction. Thus, $C$ cannot contain a non-empty strictly smaller clopen subset, as you have stated.

Comment: @Emo This is correct. An easier argument is this: If $C$ contained a clopen nontrivial subset, then we would have a splitting of the connected $C$ into non-empty disjoint open subsets.